# How to apply style in WPF to all controls without overriding their original styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, wpf-style

I want to create a style, which will normalize margins for all controls in a specific scenario:

```xml
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="MyStyle">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource DialogItemsExceptTopMargin}" />
</Style>
```

I have then a couple of different controls: textboxes, comboboxes, checkboxes etc., to which I want to apply this style.

However, when I do that, their look is immediately reverted to the platform style (I am applying a style from 3rd party library). How can I define my style so that the original styles are kept intact?

Mind: I know, that I can use BasedOn for *specific type*:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
...
</Style>
```

This however would require me to create completely separate styles for all possible controls, which I may use. I tried this trick with `FrameworkElement` and `Control`, but I got an error, that there is no such `StaticResource`.

Comment: You can only have the one style on a framework element. You could iterate all child controls from window down and set margin on them.

Comment: Could you obtain the source for your library? You could change the styling to use basedon for all the styles in there.  Maybe manipulate soufce for a resourcedictionary using code